# How to handle multiple images from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm relatively new to XCode and I don't understand how to allow the user to pick multiple images from the UIImagePickerControler. This is my current code that allows the user to pick one image:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
```

Then, to process the image selected, I use:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //do stuff with image
}
```

How do I modify both parts of the code to allow the user to pick more than one image. Thanks in advance.

Guvvy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIImagePickerController does not have an API for multiple image picking afaik - but this might give you a start:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/55351-uiimagepickercontroller-multi-select-photos.html

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [Asset Library APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722). They let you do what ImagePicker does internally. You can then add on top of that your own logic (i.e. multiselect).
 [Here's a nice tutorial for that.](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to build your custom interface for this to work.